# Use custom repository(Jfrog artifactory) to download and install custom .jar file before build maven project

Tags: maven, repository, artifactory

I have installed jfrog and uploaded `custom-lib.jar` file under

```
libs-release-local > com/mycompany/module/lib/1.1.1
```

Now I see that it's available on my artifactory link

```
http://10.10.23.40:8082/artifactory/libs-release-local/
```

Jfrog also gave me the dependency tag example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I want to specify in the pom file that bind this link to download and install the local repository before build, as it works on regular maven repo.
I have been struggling about hours. People write that need to create settings.xml under .m2 directory. Then generate content from Jfrog UI and paste into that file. I tried to do in this way, but didn't work for me. 
Anyway, I don't want to have extra configuration based on my local PC because our team work on this project and it would be good idea to make configuration based on pom file.
Is there any simple, quick and clear way to do solve this problem?

Comment: You can start by reading here - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository

Answer (score 0):

Your artifactory is like any other remote repository. The standard way to do this is to list the repository in the `<repositories>` section of your `settings.xml`.

Even easier is to set up a virtual repository in your artifactory that gathers all interesting repositories. Then you can put that into the `<mirror>` of your `settings.xml`.